# Is there a way to toggle the Thinkpad Privacy Guard in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, lenovo, hardware, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T480s which comes with a Display obfuscation called privacy guard. I read that this is supported since kernel 5.4. I have Ubuntu 20.04 with 5.4.0-74-generic.

But when I check it:

```bsh
$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/lcdshadow
status:         not supported
```

I wonder if there is also a hotkey predefined to toggle it on or of?